# Delete migrations files in Django

Tags: django, migration

I just created my first Django app and after a few changes in models.py I've created migrations files with `makemigrations` without applying them with migrate. Now i do not want to apply this change, can I delete migrations files directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you have not performed the migrations, it is safe to delete the migration files directly.